# How do I clear notifications in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, notifications

I want to remove the notifications which I got in my Dropbox when someone shared with me a file or a folder. The notification is still visible even though the file or folder is no longer shared with me.

I have attached a screen shot about which notifications i'm talking about.[image]

Comment: I don’t think you can (I don’t see any option for it), but I won’t post this as an answer, as I don’t know for sure.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except I just uploaded over 200 photos to my dropbox account. Now I literally have to click and wait to clear each one? I'm paying for this account too ... mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not disable or clear web console notification. Incase if you wanted to disable desktop notification you can follow the below steps to do so.

locate dropbox icon and right click the icon.
Click on  preferences --> General --> uncheck "Show desktop  notification".

Comment: maybe this feature isn't as important as others :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found a workaroud was as follows:
1.) Open a second account on dropbox. Upload three random files.
2.) Share these three random files with your dropbox account where you want to hide the notifications.
Result: What happens is that after three notifications the ones which you don't want to have visible disappear in the invisible part (as long as you don't scroll up). They will only disappear completely from the notifications after a certain time period.
This is very annoying and it should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have had success with removing the notification is to right-click on the notification and report it as spam.  A few choices for why you're reporting it will come up and you will have to choose a reason.  After you make your choice, the notification will disappear.  You'll have to do this for each  notification that you want to delete.

Answer (score -2):

Click twice on "Not now". Solved it for me. (V 19.4.12)

Answer (score -4):

if the need is very real, then saved the files you need i mean download them so you don't lose them, delete your dropbox account, and re-register with the same email, those notifications will be no more.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.